# How can I do a server-side forward from a JSF web app to a different web app?

Tags: jsf-2

I want to do a server-side forward from a JSF web app to a non-JSF web app, deployed in the same EAR. Is there a way to do this? It does not appear as though I can simply do this via the FacesContext. (Note, for more context, I am going to put data in the request object before the forward)

Comment: You mean that you want to perform a forward? (i.e. the request URL as in browser address bar remains unchanged)

Comment: Yes (I've updated the question to clarify). Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available by any of the JSF APIs. You'd need to fall back to the raw Servlet API.

First of all you need to configure the server to enable the "cross context" option in order to be able to obtain the other servlet context by [`ServletContext#getContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29). This is by default disabled on most servers. It's unclear which server you're using, so here are just some hints: for Tomcat, check the `crossContext` attribute of `context.xml` and for Glassfish, check the `crossContextAllowed` property of `glassfish-web.xml`.

Once done that, then you'll be able to obtain the other `ServletContext` by its context path in JSF as follows:

```
ServletContext currentServletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
ServletContext otherServletContext = currentServletContext.getContext("/otherContextPath");
```

Then, you need to obtain a `RequestDispatcher` from it on the path of the desired resource and invoke the [`forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) on it hereby passing the current HTTP servlet request and response.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
otherServletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/other.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

Finally, you need to inform JSF that rendering of the response is been taken over and that JSF doesn't need to do that.

```
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

You only need to make sure that this action isn't been invoked by an ajax request, but by a normal synchronous request, simply because you're fully overtaking the control over rendering the response from JSF and this way the JSF JS/Ajax engine has totally no notion that a non-XML response would be returned.

*(disclaimer: I've never used this in combination with JSF, but it works that way with "plain" JSP/Servlet and should theoretically work as good in a JSF webapp as that's just built on top of Servlet API)*

Comment: I've placed this code in an Action method tied to a <p:commandLink>. The code is executed in the Action method and no exceptions are thrown, but the redirect does not appear to be happening. Should this code not be in an Action method? Or any ideas why it might not be working?

Comment: Nevermind-- what fixed it for me was disabling ajax on the PrimeFaces command link (and for my use case, I set immediate="true")

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that wouldn't work for ajax requests at all, also not with a `render="@all"` as handling the response is completely out of control of JSF.